# How can I change the color of margin ticks of a matplotlib 3d plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

See the following code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#creates a spiral



N = 100
t = np.linspace(0,20,N)
z = 0.5*t
phi = 2*np.pi/10*t
x = np.cos(phi)
y = np.sin(phi)




fig = plt.figure(facecolor="black")
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
plt.gca().patch.set_facecolor("black")

ax.tick_params(axis='x',colors='white')
ax.tick_params(axis='y',colors='white')
ax.tick_params(axis='z',colors='white')
ax.w_xaxis.line.set_color("white")
ax.w_yaxis.line.set_color("white")
ax.w_zaxis.line.set_color("white")
ax.plot(x, y, z, c='blue')


plt.show()
```

It creates the following plot:
[image: plot]

How can I change the color of the ticks that I have surrounded by red? (all at once)